# Why is $(\vec{b} \times \vec{a}) \times \vec{b}$ non zero?

Tags: vectors

If I use the rule of vector triple product, it becomes:

$$ \vec{b} \times \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \vec{a} ( |\vec{b}|^2) - \vec{b}(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{a})$$

which is generally non-zero, but suppose I use properties of cross product:

$$ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = - \vec{b} \times \vec{a}$$

Hence,

$$ \vec{b} \times \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = - \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \times \vec{b} =  \vec{a} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{b})=0$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The vector cross product is not associative, i.e. $(\vec a \times \vec b) \times \vec c \ne \vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c)$

Comment: It‘s not associative

Comment: $b\times a\times b$ is not well defined since the vector product is not associatif.

Comment: Oh, thank you I got the mistake one. If someone writes this as an answer with providing source on where this concept is discussed, I'll accept it.

Comment: A nice demonstration of the non-associativity: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617751/proof-that-the-cross-product-is-not-associative-without-using-components

Comment: Thank you, that helped @player3236

Comment: Technically, $b×a×b$ can be rendered uniquely without parentheses as both possibilities are equal.  This equality holds iff the end members of the triple cross product are parallel or antiparallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the parenthesis makes you perform invalid transformations, because the cross product is not associative.

In fact $$\vec a\times\vec b\times\vec c$$ has no defined meaning.

---

Unless $\vec a,\vec b$ are parallel, $\vec b\times\vec a$ is orthogonal to $\vec b$, hence not parallel, and $(\vec b\times\vec a)\times\vec b$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec S= \vec P \times (\vec Q  \times \vec R)= (\vec P. \vec R) \vec Q-(\vec P. \vec Q) \vec R$

So $(\vec b \times a)\times \vec b=-\vec b\times(\vec b \times \vec a)=-[(\vec b. \vec a) \vec b- (\vec b . \vec b) \vec a] \ne 0$

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are perpendicular, then $\|\mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y}\| = \|\mathbf{x}\|\;\|\mathbf{y}\|$.  So in that case, if the two factors are nonzero, so is the cross product.  But $\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}$, so we can conclude: if $\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a}$  is nonzero, then so is $(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a})\times \mathbf{b}$.

Note, however, that if $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are parallel, then
$\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{0}$ and your conclusion fails.